# Trouble with local notification in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilocalnotification

I have an alarm clock app. It has 2 VC. VC1 is a menu VC that linked with VC2. In VC2 there's setting of alarm clock. So I have troubles with getting local notifications.

For example, if I set Alarm Clock on VC2 then I move to VC1 and then go to Home Screen I will receive a notification on the top of the screen. After clicking on notification I will move to VC1 and I will get a message. But I will get an error 'Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.VC1' (0x10ee97730) to 'MyApp.VC2' (0x10ee96bd0)'. If I set Alarm Clock on VC2 then I move to Home Screen I will receive a notification on the top of the screen. After clicking on notification I will move to VC2 and I will get a message and everything will be fine.

Other problem is setting Alarm clock on VC2 and moving to VC1 without moving to Home Screen. When time will I come my app just crashing with same error 'Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.VC1' (0x10ee97730) to 'MyApp.VC2' (0x10ee96bd0)'

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {
    let storageController = UIAlertController(title: "Alarm", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    var soundName: String = ""
    var index: Int = -1
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        soundName = userInfo["soundName"] as! String
        index = userInfo["index"] as! Int
    }

    playSound(soundName)

    let stopOption = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {
        (action:UIAlertAction)->Void in self.audioPlayer?.stop()
        let mainVC = self.window?.visibleViewController as! MainAlarmViewController


    storageController.addAction(stopOption)
    (self.window?.visibleViewController as! MainAlarmViewController).present(storageController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Does anybody know how to resolve it?

When I getting an error I see highlight of this line:

```
(self.window?.visibleViewController as! MainAlarmViewController).present(storageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thank you so much!

P.S. Maybe is it possible to make a notification on the top of a screen with a link to VC2 when app in foreground or app in VC1?

Also sometimes I'm getting a message 'Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!'

Comment: Share another view controller name.. Also share details of instance 'storageController'

Comment: When you get an error like that, type "po window" in the log, and if it doesn't come back with a nil value then take it a step forward until you find what the nil part of it was. So, "po window?.visibleViewController" would be the next try into "po (self.window?.visibleViewController as! MainAlarmViewController)"

Comment: `let storageController = UIAlertController(title: "Alarm", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)`

Comment: HomeViewController

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
(self.window?.visibleViewController as! MainAlarmViewController).present(storageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with following code

```
if let viewController = self.window?.visibleViewController {

       if viewController is MainAlarmViewController {
         // view controller is MainAlarmViewController
       } else {
         // view controller is not MainAlarmViewController
       }

       viewController.present(storageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
   print("Something wrong. Window can't provide visible view controller")
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error 'Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.VC1' (0x10ee97730) to 'MyApp.VC2' (0x10ee96bd0)' and the line 'let mainVC = self.window?.visibleViewController as! MainAlarmViewController' is highlighting